# Started a thread named AMQP Connection but has failed to stop it

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a program using spring-boot: 2.5.6 and Rabbitmq.
After I send the message using the following code

```java
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange.getName(), null, "Hello world".getBytes());
```

An error message will appear when trying to stop the application.

```text
2021-11-08 11:29:28.430  WARN 1724 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
 java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source)
 com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91)
 com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:184)
 com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:665)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Below is a copy of my configuration class:

```java
@Component
public class NotifyCompontent {

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("QUEUE_USER_NOTIFY", false);
    }

    @Bean
    FanoutExchange exchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange("EVENT_BUS_EXCHANGE");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindForUserNotify(FanoutExchange exchange, Queue queue) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange);
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue or work around it?　Thanks.

Comment: Any chances to have a simple Spring Boot project from you to reproduce and play with on our side?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I uploaded the code on github. [link(https://github.com/Gyoutou/stackoverflow-69878187)]. PS: The error only occurs on Eclipse. It does not appear on Netbeans.

Comment: Well, that's indeed might be only an Eclipse problem. You need to be sure how it works as you are going to run in the production. I doubt an Eclipse is involved over there somehow. Anyway I use an IntelliJ IDEA, so an experience might be fully different.

Comment: You have to `close()` the application context or `reset()` (`destroy()`) the `CachingConnectionFactory` (to close the connection). This should happen automatically with a properly configured Spring web application.